# Trying to get audio raw data and print it using PyAv

Tags: python, pyav

I'm new to `PyAv` library, or to audio programming in general so I apologize for any mistakes in advance.

I'm trying to load and print raw audio data from an `mp4 file`

I tried to read the `cookbook` and `google` and I got a bit confused.

If I understood correctly, from the frame I'm supposed to get the plane and then decode it but I couldn't figure out how exactly.

Any information regarding the issue would be greatly appreciated.

```
container = av.open(
    '/Users/ufk/Downloads/1.mp4')

for packet in container.demux():
    for frame in packet.decode():
        if isinstance(frame, av.audio.frame.AudioFrame):
            layout = frame.layout
            channels = layout.channels
            (chl, chr) = channels
            print (frame,
                   frame.format,
                   frame.layout,
                   frame.rate,
                   frame.samples)
            print (chl, chr)
            for plane in frame.planes:
                print(plane)
```

Comment: You need to know whether the format is packed or planar.  Most audio formats are packed (all of the channels are together in one sample before starting the next).  What do you expect to do with this data?  You can use `to_ndarray` to convert it to numpy for processing.

Comment: @TimRoberts - thanks. I want to analyze the audio, detect peeks and bpm, stuff like that

Comment: The you will almost certainly want to use numpy.  Beats per minute is not trivial to detect.  You may need to gather several samples to get enough to analyze.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks to Tim roberts help in the comments, i started using numpy arrays,
i created an empty array and appended to it in each frame. of course the audio is only a few seconds so it won't eat up the memory,
and i plotted the data to make sure that i see it correctly, and it looks good.

so the code:

```
import av
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

container = av.open(
    '2.mp3')

data = np.empty(shape=0)

for packet in container.demux():
    for frame in packet.decode():
        if isinstance(frame, av.audio.frame.AudioFrame):
            layout = frame.layout
            channels = layout.channels
            (chl, chr) = channels
            print(frame,
                  frame.format,
                  frame.layout,
                  frame.rate,
                  frame.samples)
            print(chl, chr)
            array = frame.to_ndarray()[0]
            data = np.concatenate([data, array])

plt.subplot(2, 1, 1)
plt.title("Original audio signal")
plt.plot(data)
plt.grid()
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

and the result:

[image: audio stream]