# Programmatically accessing PTS times in MP4 container

Tags: python, audio, video, ffmpeg, mp4

### Background

For a research project, we are recording video data from two cameras and feed a synchronization pulse directly into the microphone ADC every second.

### Problem

We want to derive a frame time stamp in the clock of the pulse source for each camera frame to relate the camera images temporally. With our current methods (see below), we get a frame offset of around 2 frames between the cameras. Unfortunately, inspection of the video shows that we are clearly 6 frames off (at least at one point) between the cameras.
I assume that this is because we are relating audio and video signal wrong (see below).

### Approach I think I need help with

I read that in the MP4 container, there should be PTS times for video and audio. How do we access those programmatically. Python would be perfect, but if we have to call ffmpeg via system calls, we may do that too ...

### What we currently fail with

The original idea was to find video and audio times as

```
audio_sample_times = range(N_audiosamples)/audio_sampling_rate
video_frame_times = range(N_videoframes)/video_frame_rate
```

then identify audio_pulse_times in audio_sample_times base, calculate the relative position of each video_time to the audio_pulse_times around it, and select the same relative value to the corresponding source_pulse_times.

However, a first indication that this approach is problematic is already that for some videos, N_audiosamples/audio_sampling_rate differs from N_videoframes/video_frame_rate by multiple frames.

### What I have found by now

OpenCV's cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC seems to do exactly what we do, and not access any PTS ...

### Edit: What I took from the winning answer

```
container = av.open(video_path)
signal = []
audio_sample_times = []
video_sample_times = []

for frame in tqdm(container.decode(video=0, audio=0)):
    if isinstance(frame, av.audio.frame.AudioFrame):
        sample_times = (frame.pts + np.arange(frame.samples)) / frame.sample_rate
        audio_sample_times += list(sample_times)
        signal_f_ch0 = frame.to_ndarray().reshape((-1, len(frame.layout.channels))).T[0]
        signal += list(signal_f_ch0)
    elif isinstance(frame, av.video.frame.VideoFrame):
        video_sample_times.append(float(frame.pts*frame.time_base))

signal = np.abs(np.array(signal))
audio_sample_times = np.array(audio_sample_times)
video_sample_times = np.array(video_sample_times)
```

Unfortunately, in my particular case, all pts are consecutive and gapless, so the result is the same as with the naive solution ...
By picture clues, we identified a section of ~10s in the videos, somewhere in which they desync, but can't find any traces of that in the data.

Comment: **(1)** It sounds like you expect PTS to be a timestamp of the real-world clock? (_eg:_ the date/time of this frame's creation)?.. PTS is just for telling the decoder when to display a frame on screen (related to since when playback began). It will be zero for each first frame in both videos, so you cannot calculate any delay from that...

Comment: **(2)** You need to set a constant bitrate (CBR) on the audio settings, then from each video you convert the audio into PCM (to get an array of the audio wave's amplitudes) and look for the values that represent your pulse... Then calculate `msec_time_of_Pulse` as `= (audio_sampling_rate / 1000) * Num_audiosamples_until_Pulse` to get media time of pulse (_eg:_ `(44100 / 1000) x 55000_samples` = 1247 millisecs or 1.247 secs)... Then simply seek the video to that time to see the corresponding frame image at time of pulse...

Comment: **(3)** Use the detected start time of first pulse in each video to know the offset or delay between the two pulses. You can use that time to calculate expected frame number as `(video_FPS / 1000) * msec_time_of_Pulse`

Comment: @VC.One Regading (1), I certainly expeccct a real world clock, but common clock ... And I hoped for it to be more sophisticated that what I get from your calculations. It seems to me, those could run apart when the frame/sampling rates are slightly inaccurate.
Regarding (2) and (3), I don't really see the difference to what I describe under "What we currently fail with" ... With that approach, we get an offset of 6 frames towards the end of the video from external clues, while the first pulse offset is only 2 frames.

Comment: Don't know how I ended up here (again) from Google searching an MP4 issue. Sorry for the suspense... **(1)** The nearest thing to a real-world clock is if those cameras are adding a "creation date" in the MP4 metadata. Its a 50/50 chance but most software & hardware do add it. Check your file with an online tool like [MediaInfo](https://mediaarea.net/MediaInfoOnline) for any "date" related metadata. **(2)** _"Those could run apart when the frame/sampling rates are slightly inaccurate"_ Not if you use **Constant** bit-rate (CBR). Are your cameras recording audio as **Variable** bit rate (VBR)?

Comment: **PS:** Not sure how you are getting an offset. You say the PTS values are gapless (I assume meaning they increase at constant/regular intervals?). It would all be easier to assess if we had access to test files. For example what is the "external clues" in _"We get an offset of 6 frames towards the end of the video from external clues"_. Most likely the problem is solved now, so no worries. **PPS:** The PTS times are found in `stts` section of MP4 header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run `ffprobe` to retrieve the PTS times. I don't know the exact command, but if you're ok with another package, try [`ffmpegio`](https://github.com/python-ffmpegio/python-ffmpegio):

```
pip install ffmpegio-core 

// OR 

pip install ffmpegio // if you also want to use it to read video frames & audio samples
```

If you're on Windows, see [this doc](https://python-ffmpegio.github.io/python-ffmpegio/install.html) on where ffmpeg.exe can be found automatically.

Then if you can run

```py
import ffmpegio

frames = ffmpegio.probe.frames('video.mp4', intervals=10)
```

This will return the frames info as a `list` of `dict`s of the first 10 packets (of mixed streams in the order of pts). If you remove the `intervals` argument, it'll retrieve every frame (will take a long time).

Inspect each `dict` of `frames` and decide which entries you need (say 'media_type', 'stream_index', `pts` and `pts_time`). Then add `entries` argument containing these:

```py
frames = ffmpegio.probe.frames('video.mp4', intervals=10, 
                               entries=['media_type', 'stream_index', 'pts','pts_time'])
```

Once you're happy with what it returns, incorporate to your program.

The `intervals` argument accepts many different formats, please read [the doc](https://python-ffmpegio.github.io/python-ffmpegio/probe.html#ffmpegio.probe.frames).

What this or any other FFmpeg-based approach does not offer you is getting this info with the data frames. You need to read in the frame timing data separately and mesh them with the data yourself. If you prefer a solution with more control (but perhaps more coding) look into [pyav](https://github.com/PyAV-Org/PyAV), which interfaces the underlying library of FFmpeg. I'm fairly certain you can retrieve pts simultaneously with framedata.

Disclaimer: This function has not been tested extensively. So, you may encounter an issue. If you have, please report on GitHub and I'll fix it asap.

Comment: (1) First of all, thanks! I tested around a bit, and I think I understood more about the format.  Is this correct so far?:
For video, each frames contains one image, and for audio, a variable amount of samples, here mostly 1024, every 5th 314.
From each frame, I take the (pts+range(n_samples)*time_base for the times of the samples in that package.
I can get the data as described in
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73198826/trying-to-get-audio-raw-data-and-print-it-using-pyav
Unfortunately, the PTS from audio are consecutive. I hoped for gaps for some reason. So it seems, my problem ...

Comment: (2) from my "naive" solution still persists, even if I make use of the presentation time info in the container. Maybe a delay between hardware video and audio decoder ... Guess we have to do some test videos with a synchronization light.
Or did I miss anything?

Comment: >"(pts+range(n_samples)*time_base" - you got it

Comment: > the PTS from audio are consecutive - It depends on the container format, but when audio and video frame interval lines up, that would be the most efficient time_base choice. So, it doesn't surprise me that's the case.

Comment: Thanks. With the consecutive sentence, I meant that they actually are in my case. 
so in *my case* [video_frame0_pts, video_frame1_pts, ...]*video_time_base == range(n_frames)*video_time_base and [audi_frame0_pts+range(audi_frame0_samples), audi_frame1_pts+range(audi_frame1_samples),, ...]*audio_time_base == range(n_all_samples)*audio_time_base and the result is the same as before.
Unfortunately, by now we found that the cameras desync at a particular time without any hint of anything weird going on at that time.

Comment: Anyway, thanks again. I added my final code to the question for completeness, as it answers the question, albeit not solve my problem :)